# swap functions for lvalue and rvalue references

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am writing a vector class which has move constructor and move assignment operator.
Apart from that I have this swap function:

```
template<typename T>
    void vector<T>::swap_( vector& rhs){
        using std::swap;
        swap( m_data, rhs.m_data );
        swap( m_size, rhs.m_size );
        swap( m_capacity, rhs.m_capacity );
    }
```

Since rvalues don't bind with non-const lvalue references, I am gonna need an identical swap function for rvalue references with the only difference in the type of the parameter. Is there any way I can avoid duplicating the code?

Comment: You don't need it. Just be sure to call it `rvalue.swap_(lvalue);`

Comment: Why would you want to swap with rvalues? No std type does that, afaik. Just assign.

Comment: @DanM. - There's the classic trick to kinda myabe force shrink a vector.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks!

Comment: @StoryTeller there's a `shrink_to_fit` in all implementations that have rvalue references though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need another version of your swap function.  In your move assignment operator you'll have a signature like

```
template<typename T>
vector<T>& vector<T>::operator=(vector<T>&& tmp)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

in the `do stuff` part `tmp` is no longer an rvalue.  Since it has a name, it is a lvalue and you can call your swap function on it.   That means the implementation would be

```
template<typename T>
vector<T>& vector<T>::operator=(vector<T>&& tmp)
{
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

and now your object has the others guts and vice versa.

You can do the same thing with your move constructor.  You delegate to the default constructor so your new object gets default initialized and then you swap that default instance into the rvalue.  That looks like

```
template<typename T>
vector<T>::vector<T>(vector<T>&& tmp) : vector<T>()
{
    swap(tmp);
}
```